# Apollo BLE Communication

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, apollo

I'm trying to communicate with BLE between Android App and Apollo devices.But When App is running normally, |App and Apollo device don't communicate well
What I want to know is Apollo device'BLE device communication type and communication's max length.

I'm new to BLE.
I already downloaded BLE-master(Android App source code) and used Apollo SDK(osaap-uart-server.uvprojx).
And also used  Keil 5.20 for device programming.
when Android App and Apollo device is connecting, communication length is limit to 20cm.
I don't know the reason why the distance is so small.
How do I do to increase communiation distance?

Apollo advertising code are follows .